# String changed after convertion from Excel to CSV

Tags: excel, csv, spreadsheet

I am trying to convert excel sheet to csv.
But my cell record `19367900799303` changed to `19367900000000`.
I tried by changing all datatypes (format cells) including number and text but same result received.
Just one solution I found that set datatype of cell to text and copy text from the cell and again past it to cell. This marks a green dot on the top-left corner of cell and value remains consistent after csv conversion.
But I cannot apply this practice on thousands of records that I have.

I am using Excel 2010 please tell me any solution.

Comment: That will happen if you open the csv file in Excel directly as it will interpret that as a numeric data type and Excel will only display 15 significant digits. (Note: that doesn't mean that the actual csv file contains the altered data). If you need to open it in Excel, you should **import** so that you can specify that field is Text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also wondering in this problem. I solved the issue as follows:

1. Create a new column (next to the column `suppose A:A` which is require to be
       converted to string).
2. Apply formula to first cell of new column `=TEXT(A1, 0)`.
3. Drag or copy/past the above formula to entire column.
4. Copy the entire new column and past `As Values`.

Now this is pure text and remains unchanged after csv conversion.